# React Navigation 6 and React Native 0.71 back button on android is not navigating back through history after switching tabs

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Essentially, there is a pattern of navigation that is common where the all navigation that happens in an app can be navigated backwards with the physical back button or back gesture. This is how Instagram works too.

For some reason this doesn't seem to be the case in my React Native project.. The back button works until we get down to the tab stack. where then the android back button just does nothing. I would expect it to go back to the previous tab.

for example, we are on tab 1, navigate to tab 2, and then tab 3. I expect pressing the back button will nav through these one press at a time (3 -> 2 -> 1).

Instead it just stays on tab 3. Of course, if I click into screens inside the stack of tab three, the back button will work all the way to the first screen in that tab stack.

I've tried the backBehavior prop "history" and "none" and neither seem to make a difference..

Any ideas here? Shouldn't this just work? Thanks